# Nodatime throwing exception in UWP app targeting Windows 10 10240

Tags: c#, uwp, nodatime

Hi I'm building a Windows 10 app and  I'm using NodaTime 2.4.0 to handle some timezone scenarios. Whilst on debug mode it's working fine, this peace of code throws an "Aggregate Exception" with not much detail.

```
  private void SetDateTime()
    {          
        _currentTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
    }
```

Which yields the exception:

```
+       [0] {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Excep_FromHResult 0x80070002)}    System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}
```

I'm compiling the app on Release using .net Native an targeting 10240. Any ideas why it's happening? thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from that line? Also maybe the GetSystemDefault is looking for a file somewhere, are you on a different machine when the error occurs perhaps?

Comment: .. just a side question... what are you doing with:  (string utcStartTime, string timeZoneValue)... Looks to be nothing.  With that said, and given that we only have a micro sample of your code... I would say, set some breakpoints and step through it... an "Aggregate Exception" would be a PTL exception, and you haven't included that code.

Comment: It's an aggregate exception, with FileNotFoundException as an InnerException in it. I'm in the same developer laptop, just switch from debug, to release. and that exception happens always in the same line.

Comment: the innerexception is a `FileNotFoundException`. missing tzdb files?

Comment: It looks like, that'ts the only information I have.

Comment: I assume this works in debug mode with .net native compiler disabled? If this code is in another assembly (other than the main assembly for your app) you might have to add the nuget package to the main assembly too.

Comment: Could you check whether `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"]` works, for example? And separately, check whether `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` works? It would be useful to separate "Loading the TZDB resource" from "Getting the system default time zone"

Comment: Hi Jon, `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` does work properly but `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"]`  yields the same aggregate exception.

Comment: Hi @etragu the  method return correct time zone in release mode in my side . Have your tried to use earlier `NodaTime` version or tested in another computer?

Comment: In release mode is fine, but you have to activate .net Native in the build configuration

Comment: what mean that activate .net Native? check compile with .net native tool chain?

Comment: exactly, targeting Windows 10240, enabling "Compile with .net native tool chain" and "Enable static analysis for .net native"

Comment: I have tried with both check, it also work well. very strange issue, could you tried to test with blank app?

Comment: Tried in a blank project but is working fine there, but on my project is failing :(

Comment: Please open your project with admin and re-install the nuget package.

Comment: So you can't reproduce this (even with .NET Native) in a fresh project? That's going to make it hard to help you fix, certainly. It might help if you could show the full stack trace, if you still get one.

Comment: Any more information on this? Without more information, I don't think we're going to be able to help.

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm not able to reproduce it, will keep you updated if I see something else. Thanks anyways.